# Convert SQL into HQL where clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

this should be easy, but my app throws constant error, and I'm new to Hibernate.

I am trying to have simple HQL query in my web app using Hibernate.

I want to execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM deal WHERE deal_status='A' OR WHERE deal_status='O';
```

HQL does not seem to work with or clause, here my current HQL statements in my web app:

```
FROM deal d where d.deal_status='O' or d.deal_status='A' order by d.id
```

Thanks for any Hibernate query help

Regards
Alex

Comment: Post your error exception, and you do know that HQL is based on your entity classes, and not on your DB schema?

Comment: There is a syntax error in your SQL: you must write only one WHERE

Comment: that was my stupid issue, thx jishi !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The HQL is based on the name of fields of your entity not of your class, and the Class Names
- `c.id` - c is not defined

I strongly assume that the fields in Deal (Classname first letter upper case) are not `deal_status` but status, then the query must be like this. (I skipped the c.id stuff, because I have no idea what you mean by this.)

```
 SELECT d FROM Deal d WHERE d.status='O' or d.status=`A`
```

*Notice the upper D from Deal*

And this will only work if Deal.status is a String or something like that, but not if it is a Enum. One way to handle an Enum is this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
    "SELECT d FROM Deal d WHERE d.status=:o or d.status=:a");
query.setParameter("a", MyEnum.A);
query.setParameter("o", MyEnum.O);
```

Comment: How do you do it with an ENUM type ?? as it is one !!

Comment: <property column="deal_status" length="1" name="dealStatus" not-null="true">
            <type name="nl.strohalm.cyclos.utils.hibernate.StringValuedEnumType">
                <param name="enumClassName">nl.strohalm.cyclos.entities.coupon.Coupon$DealStatus</param>
            </type>
        </property>

Comment: @Alexander Grosse: see my extended answer